# Heapsort recursivo em C

Tags: c, algoritmo

Eu tenho um heapsort, e gostaria de implementar ele recursivo. O que eu preciso mudar no meu algoritmo?

```
void criarHeap(int v[], int inicio, int final){
    int aux = v[inicio];//v[pai]//inicio=pai
    int filho = (inicio * 2)+1;//i=filho
while(filho<=final){
    if(filho<final && (filho+1)<final){
        if(v[filho]<v[filho+1]){//pai tem 2 filhos ? se sim, qual o maior
            filho++;
        }
    }
    if(aux<v[filho]){//troca o filho com o pai se o filho for maior
        v[inicio]=v[filho];
        inicio=filho;
        filho=(2*inicio)+1;
    }
    else{
        filho=final+1;
    }
}
    v[inicio] = aux;//pai troca com filho mais profundo mais a direita
}

void heapSort(int v[], int tam){
    int i;
    int aux;
    for(i=(tam-1)/2;i>=0;i--){// cria heap
        criarHeap(v,i,tam-1);
    }
    for(i=tam-1;i>=1;i--){//pega o maior elemento e coloca na posicao o array
        aux = v[0];
        v[0]=v[i];
        v[i]=aux;
        criarHeap(v,0,i-1);//cria o heap sem o maior elemento anterior
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, criei um teste para o seu algoritmo:

```
int main(void) {
    int teste[] = {8, 4, 2, 9, 5, 0, 10, 7, 1, 3, 6};
    heapSort(teste, 11);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        printf("%i ", teste[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A saída foi a esperada: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`. [**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/XwA43Z)

Então, agora podemos mexer no seu código. O primeiro passo é transformar o `while` da função `criarHeap` em uma recursão.

Vemos que esse `while` altera a variável `filho` que será utilizada após o término desse laço. Assim, a função recursiva que irá substituir esse `while` poderá retornar o valor dessa variável. As variáveis que são utilizadas nesse `while` e que são recebidas externamente são `v`, `inicio`, `aux`, `filho` e `final`, logo essas tornam-se os parâmetros para a função recursiva.

O código fica assim:

```
int criarHeapRecursao(int v[], int inicio, int aux, int filho, int final) {
    if (filho > final) return inicio;

    // Pai tem 2 filhos? Se sim, qual é o maior?
    if (filho < final && filho + 1 < final && v[filho] < v[filho + 1]) {
        filho++;
    }

    // Troca o filho com o pai se o filho for maior.
    if (aux < v[filho]) {
        v[inicio] = v[filho];
        inicio = filho;
        filho = 2 * inicio + 1;
    } else {
        filho = final + 1;
    }
    return criarHeapRecursao(v, inicio, aux, filho, final);
}

void criarHeap(int v[], int inicio, int final) {
    int aux = v[inicio];
    int filho = inicio * 2 + 1;
    inicio = criarHeapRecursao(v, inicio, aux, filho, final);
    v[inicio] = aux; // Pai troca com filho mais profundo mais a direita.
}
```

Observe que a recursão está no final da função `criarHeapRecursao` e aquilo que era a condição de parada do `while` tornou-se um `if` no início da função.

Feito isso, agora temos a função `heapSort` que tem dois laços. Cada laço vai virar uma função recursiva a parte. A condição de parada é colocada como um `if` no início da função e o contador torna-se um dos parâmetros de cada uma dessas funções recursivas. As demais variáveis utilizadas nos laços (`v` e `tam`) também tornam-se parâmetros. A chamada recursiva é colocada ao final de cada fução. O resultado é isso:

```
void heapSort1(int v[], int i, int tam) {
    if (i < 0) return;
    criarHeap(v, i, tam - 1);
    heapSort1(v, i - 1, tam);
}

void heapSort2(int v[], int i, int tam) {
    if (i <= 0) return;
    int aux = v[0];
    v[0] = v[i];
    v[i] = aux;
    criarHeap(v, 0, i - 1); // Cria o heap sem o maior elemento anterior.
    heapSort2(v, i - 1, tam);
}

void heapSort(int v[], int tam) {
    heapSort1(v, (tam - 1) / 2, tam);
    heapSort2(v, tam - 1, tam);
}
```

Desta forma, os laços da função `heapSort` foram convertidos nas funções recursivas `heapSort1` e `heapSort2`.

A variável `aux` tinha um escopo onde era utilizada apenas dentro do segundo laço, mas o seu valor não era utilizado entre uma iteração e outra, não fazia sentido antes da primeira iteração e nem era usada após a última iteração. Por esse motivo, ela tornou-se uma variável local de `heapSort2`.

A saída permanece a esperada, `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`. [**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/1ELXWl)